# Cannot get the download link after uploading files to firebase storage Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

so this is the my file picking and file upload code

```
class Storage with ChangeNotifier {
  PlatformFile? pickedFile;
  UploadTask? uploadTask;

  Future uploadFile() async {
    final path = 'files/${pickedFile!.name}.png';
    final file = File(pickedFile!.path!);

    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path);
    ref.putFile(file);

    

    try {
      final snapshot = await uploadTask!.whenComplete(() {});
      final urlDownload = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      print(urlDownload);
    } catch (e) {
      print("this is the error $e " );
    }
  }

  void pickFile() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

    if (result != null) {
      File file = File(result.files.single.path!);
      pickedFile = result.files.first;
    } else {
      print("no image picked");
    }}}
```

the code works for upload the image but after that i didnt get any download link, the error is "Null check operator used on a null value" i dont know how to fix it, im still new in this topic, help please

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer, need to change the uploadFile method to this

```
Future uploadFile() async {
final path = 'files/${pickedFile!.name}.png';
final file = File(pickedFile!.path!);

FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
Reference ref = storage.ref().child(path);
UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);
uploadTask.then((res) {
  res.ref.getDownloadURL();
});



try {
  final snapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});
  final urlDownload = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  print(urlDownload);
} catch (e) {
  print("this is the error $e " );
}
```

}

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?